# create a Folder Content type that automatically creates Sub Folders in the New Folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, content-type, subdirectory

Is it possible to create a Folder Content type that automatically creates Sub Folders in the New Folder created in the SharePoint Document Library ?

Comment: Do you mean by the SharePoint UI, or as a developer?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, you can use Visual Studio to create a SharePoint project that adds your new custom content type to a site collection and also attaches an event receiver to the content type.

In the OnCreated event handler, you can include code that automatically creates subfolders whenever an item is created using your custom content type.